# Capitalize first letter of every word in a string Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Below I have written my code, apparently there is a parameter declaration issue. Can someone please point out where such issue is?

```js
//Title case
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  let result = str.map(function(val {
    return val.replace(val.charAt(0), val.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
  }) return str = result.join(" ");)
}
console.log(titleCase("I am a little tea pot")); //I Am A Little Tea Pot
```

Comment: typo in your code. Get a tool like eslint that will point these out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function(val {` is missing the closing arguments bracket.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  let result = str.map(function(val){
    return val.replace(val.charAt(0), val.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
  })
  return str = result.join(" ");
}
console.log(titleCase("I am a little tea pot")); //I Am A Little Tea Pot
```